# What is hudsonenv.properties stands for in ANT xml file?

Tags: xml, ant, build, jenkins, clearcase

I'm new to ANT, i have an XML file that has some property that i'm not familiar with.

```
<property file="${env.CLEARCASE_VIEWPATH}/${vobtag}/${sub.vob.component}/hudsonenv.properties"/>
<property name="filePath" value="/${env.CLEARCASE_VIEWPATH}/${vobtag}/${sub.vob.component}/hudsonenv.properties"/>
<echo>File Path: ${filePath}</echo>
```

I'd like to know what is "`hudsonenv.properties`".

When I'm trying to print it to see what is the value or which directory is `hudsonenv.properties`, I'm getting the following:

```
[echo] File Path: //ccstore/builder/hudson/workspace/RavenApp1.5.5.0_Plat_Mig/builder_RavenApp1.5.5.0_Plat_Mig/vobs/ravenp/hudsonenv.properties
```

I'll really appreciate if anybody will help me to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

> what is the value or which directory is `hudsonenv.properties`

It is in a `clearcase view/vob/a component/`: `hudsonenv.properties`

It means, depending on the config spec used for those Jenkins/Hudson views, that you can access that same file in a view configured to oad (snapshot) or mount (dynamic) the same vob.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, there's no such file called "hudsonenv.properties". It *has* to be a custom file which somebody created. It's a good practice to use properties file for specifying property name and its corresponding value. Hopefully, there should be a string in your XML file with the name 'property file'. Something like:

```
<property file="build.properties"/>
```

If it's there, then check this file and you might find the "hudsonenv.properties" set here to the path that's printing in the `echo` statement.